# how to get value of option/text in html without submitting a form

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I want to use value of text box in form in which its written for a query.Here is my code.

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <label>Subject</label>
    //I can use option also here
    <input type="text" maxlength="30" name="subject" />
    <?php
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM STUDENT where subject="textbox.text"");
    ?>
</form>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: There has to be a http call to trigger something.. So it is either  through AJAX or regular submit

Comment: Because I don't know ajax... :)

Comment: Then please help me in doing it with ajax.

Comment: Well. I don't know how to speak when I was young, and then I learned to.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, html/javascript are only on the client browser. what you want is not possible without some form of communication between the client/server.

Comment: AJAX isn't a language, it's a concept.  JQuery is a somewhat easy way to achieve AJAX-style behavior.  I recommend you take a look at it or the raw Javascript necessary for an AJAX call.

Comment: @Naeem Shakir -its unclear what you are wanting to do, do you just want to be able to use the value of the "subject" input box in your javascript or to submit it without user clicking or pressing enter?  If the former, see my post, if the latter see: XMLHttpRequest (the main part of AJAX that everyone talks about but never explains) http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is with an AJAX-style call or by submitting the form.

Your server needs the information from the drop down in order to provide a response.  If the web browser never submits another request (either by AJAX or form submission), there's no way for the server to act upon it.

Comment: how I will do it with ajax style?

Comment: I think you'll probably need to step back and understand Ajax better.  I recommend you look up an AJAX tutorial as what you're asking for is more like teaching an entire concept than an individual question.

Answer (score 0):

you can poll document.getElementsByName("subject")[0].value)

```
yourFunction(document.getElementsByName("subject")[0].value);
```

where your function could insert a script tag, make an XMLHttpRequest, etc...

Edit: for older versions of IE, use ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") in place of XMLHttpRequest()